# Virtual Environment python.exe calling Global python.exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-venv

Currently, I have a Python project that contains a `virtualenv` instance of Python in its folder. Using VS Code to open that folder, and then having the interpreter set to the virtual environment ".venv", it should then run Python scripts via that virtual environment. But what happens is that once I use the python.exe to run a script within that virtual environment that I've activated, it will then spawn a child process that calls the exact python command, but with the global instance instead.

Steps to reproduce what I am seeing (currently using Windows 10):

1. Install Python 3.11 for all users
2. run `pip install virtualenv`
3. cd to the folder with my Python project
4. run `virtualenv .venv`
5. append `$env:PYTHONPATH = ".\src\WPL-API;$env:PYTHONPATH"` to the end of the `activate.ps1` script that was just created, so that my virtual environment will use the code in `.\src\WPL-API` as well
6. Launch VS Code, open the project folder that I created this virtual environment in
7. Set the Python interpreter to `('.venv': venv)`, instead of the one marked Global
8. Launch a new terminal (PowerShell, the one installed with W10), which will then trigger the updated `activate.ps1` script
9. In that activated terminal within VS Code, call `python` with the .py file that I want to run

Once doing all of the above steps, I can see with Process Explorer that the local python.exe file calls the global python.exe, using the same arguments.

[What I am seeing currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4no3.png)

---

Is there a way that I can get my virtual environment to stop calling the global python.exe instance, and just have it run the script itself? I can confirm that I see `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Documents\GitHub\Work\WPL_API\.venv/Scripts` as the first item in the `PATH` after running the activation script, but wasn't sure if there's something else that I need to do to the `PATH` so that this runs properly.

Comment: Isn't it normal? Is there an actual issue? Does the execution use the libraries from the virtual environment or not?

Comment: @sinoroc Well I suppose I wasn't sure what would happen in the case where my main Python installation gets updated. Currently if I run the `import os` command, it will import from the main Python location, but what if that main install gets updated? Basically I was hoping that the virtual environment would be completely separated from the main installation, so that any changes to it don't affect the virtual environment. Or is that intended behavior.

I tried looking online for any description on what gets copied over when running `virtualenv`, but couldn't find that answer.

Comment: Virtual environments are mostly about having an isolated place to install third party libraries (_pip_-install), the rest (interpreter and standard library) still comes from the "main" Python installation, the one used to create the environment, -- So it seems like normal expected behavior to me. -- No, a virtual environment is not independent from the interpreter used to create the environment.

Comment: If you update Python and want to keep the virtual environment working, you should make sure to keep the same major and minor version the same, only update the bugfix/maintenance version. In other words, if you create a virtual environment with Python 3.10.1 for example, then you can update it to 3.10.2, 3.10.3, any 3.10.X, but not 3.11. Which is the normal behavior of update installers anyway. -- Also it is perfectly fine to have both Python 3.10.x and Python 3.11.y on the same computer. But I would recommend against trying to have Python 3.10.x and Python 3.10.y at the same time.

Comment: So if I install Python 3.10.X onto my machine alongside the 3.11.X install, run virtualenv on 3.10.X for a folder, and have the 3.11.X install at the front of the PATH, would that environment start using 3.11.X? Or is there something in that virtual environment that says that it will continue to use 3.10.X, despite a different version being at the front of the PATH?

Comment: Oh just ran into the pyvenv.cfg file, and see that it's referencing the path to my 3.11.X installation. I'm  assuming that this would answer my question then. So that would make sense then, where installing different versions of Python on my machine would not affect the virtual environment, as long as I install that different major/minor version in a folder that's separate from the one listed in the pyvenv.cfg file.

Comment: Exactly. If you create a virtual environment with Python 3.10.1, and then later update to 3.10.2 the virtual environment should still work. It will work as long as there is a Python 3.10 at that location.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my issue, where the `pyvenv.cfg` file that gets created after running `virtualenv` would state which directory it will run Python from. I was under the assumption that virtual environments would copy everything over from the Python installation that you call `virtualenv` on, but instead the virtual environment has a hard link back to that original path.

So therefore, as long as I don't install a different major/minor version over an existing one (e.g. don't install a future 3.12.X in my 3.11.X folder), then my virtual environment should still be safe (since it would then be referencing the path to the 3.11.X folder at this time). And of course, my virtual environment will have its separate packages as intended.

Thanks @sinoroc!